# Cyclic depenency: IVisitor and Datas

Tags: c#, .net, solid-principles, visitor-pattern, cyclic-dependency

I recently asked about cyclic dependency. The answer was to dedicate a project on interfaces (`MyProject.Abstractions`). Now, this project is the cause of another cyclic dependency, with a Visitor pattern.

```
namespace MyProject.Abstractions
{
    public interface ICharacter { }

    public interface ICharacterVisitor
    {
        // References MyProject.Characters
        void Visit(Warrior warrior);
        void Visit(Wizard wizard);
    }
}

namespace MyProject.Characters
{
    // References MyProject.Abstractions
    public abstract class CharacterBase : ICharacter { }

    public class Warrior : CharacterBase { }
    public class Wizard : CharacterBase { }
}
```

Does it mean that my ICharacterVisitor should be in my `MyProject.Characters` project ? I dedicate this entire solution to be my SOLID training exercice.

Comment: `void Visit(IWarrior warrior)` would help you move your dependency to abstraction from concrete classes. The problem here is depending on concrete Warrior Class, if you depend on abstract IWarrior interface this cyclic dependency will go away

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The visitor is a tool that applies to an existing structure but is not a part of it. Therefore I would separate the visitor from the data you are visiting.

```
namespace MyProject.Abstractions.Characters
{
    public interface ICharacter { }
}
```

```
using MyProject.Abstractions.Characters;

namespace MyProject.Characters
{
    public abstract class CharacterBase : ICharacter { }

    public class Warrior : CharacterBase { }
    public class Wizard : CharacterBase { }
}
```

```
using MyProject.Abstractions.Characters;
using MyProject.Characters;

namespace MyProject.Abstractions.Visitors
{
    public interface ICharacterVisitor
    {
        // References MyProject.Characters
        void Visit(Warrior warrior);
        void Visit(Wizard wizard);
    }
}
```

```
using MyProject.Abstractions.Characters;
using MyProject.Abstractions.Visitors
using MyProject.Characters;

namespace MyProject.Visitors
{
    // Concrete visitors here
}
```

You don't necessarily need to have a separate project for each namespace. The visitor stuff could be in the same project as `MyProject.Characters`. SOLID is about a logical organization of code, not a physical. This answer to [benefits of multiple Projects and One Solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8678287/880990) lists good reasons for having multiple projects.

Answer (score 0):

By its nature the visitor pattern does tend to a introduce cyclic dependency - the visitor interface must know about all the different classes it operates on, and each of those must somehow know how to call the right method on the visitor, which means knowing the visitor class.

You *can* break this cyclic dependency by doing something like:

```
// Abstractions project
interface ICharacter
{
    string Name { get; } 
}
interface IWarrior : ICharacter
{
    void Attack();
}
interface IWizard : ICharacter
{
    void CastSpell();
}
interface IVisitor
{
    void Visit(IWarrior w);
    void Visit(IWizard w);
}
// implementations project
abstract class CharacterBase : ICharacter
{
    public string Name { get; }
    public abstract void Accept(IVisitor v);
}
class Warrior : CharacterBase, IWarrior
{
    public void Attack()
    {
        // do warrior things
    }
    public override void Accept(IVisitor v)
    {
        v.Visit(this);
    }
}
class Wizard : CharacterBase, IWizard
{
    public void CastSpell()
    {
        // do wizardly things
    }
    public override void Accept(IVisitor visitor)
    {
        visitor.Visit(this);
    }
}
```

Assuming you actually need the "CharacterBase" class to hold some sort of shared functionality/properties between characters.

Whether it's worthwhile is a call you'll have to make, as the nature of the Visitor pattern is the real issue - how likely are you to add more character types in the future? How likely are you to add more visitors?  Is there a way you have can each type of character decide for itself what actions it needs to take in particular scenarios?